# Facing a lot of issues after upgrading to 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04

I recently updated my system to 18.04.2 the kernel version is 4.18.0-15-generic and I'm following following issues:

1. After the boot starts up the lockscreen is never loading and i see a splash/flashing screen continously.
2. When i lock my laptop and when i want to sign in back the same splash/flashing screen is seen again i need to force shutdown my laptop and start again.

Is this a bug?